# What are the default blockly blocks?

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/toolbox) shows use of some sample blocks, but I can't find a definitive list. I found a [gist](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjyqJWDzcLmAhVJo54KHXRsDbcQFjAEegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fdavidferguson%2Ff85e1ae84b940bf8398f9bdbe98a4d8f&usg=AOvVaw1EafViZ9AA_Y7Ygy1C6lZO) that is the type of list that I want, but it isn't official. The GitHub repository contains a set of json [files](https://github.com/google/blockly/tree/master/blocks) that appear to implement the defaults. Then there is [blocks_compressed.js](https://github.com/google/blockly/blob/master/blocks_compressed.js), but that's surely not meant to be documentation of what is available. There is the [Wiki](https://github.com/google/blockly/wiki), but it isn't complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I pulled this out of one of the blockly demos, it seems pretty comprehensive but I don't know if it is the full set.

```html
<xml xmlns="https://developers.google.com/blockly/xml" id="toolbox-categories">
<category name="Logic" categorystyle="logic_category">
  <block type="controls_if"></block>
  <block type="logic_compare"></block>
  <block type="logic_operation"></block>
  <block type="logic_negate"></block>
  <block type="logic_boolean"></block>
  <block type="logic_null" disabled="true"></block>
  <block type="logic_ternary"></block>
</category>
<category name="Loops" categorystyle="loop_category">
  <block type="controls_repeat_ext">
    <value name="TIMES">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">10</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="controls_repeat" disabled="true"></block>
  <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
  <block type="controls_for">
    <value name="FROM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="TO">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">10</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="BY">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="controls_forEach"></block>
  <block type="controls_flow_statements"></block>
</category>
<category name="Math" categorystyle="math_category">
  <block type="math_number" gap="32">
    <field name="NUM">123</field>
  </block>
  <block type="math_arithmetic">
    <value name="A">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="B">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_single">
    <value name="NUM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">9</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_trig">
    <value name="NUM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">45</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_constant"></block>
  <block type="math_number_property">
    <value name="NUMBER_TO_CHECK">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">0</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_round">
    <value name="NUM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">3.1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_on_list"></block>
  <block type="math_modulo">
    <value name="DIVIDEND">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">64</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="DIVISOR">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">10</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_constrain">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">50</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="LOW">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="HIGH">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">100</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_random_int">
    <value name="FROM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="TO">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">100</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="math_random_float"></block>
  <block type="math_atan2">
    <value name="X">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="Y">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">1</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
</category>
<category name="Text" categorystyle="text_category">
  <block type="text"></block>
  <block type="text_multiline"></block>
  <block type="text_join"></block>
  <block type="text_append">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_length">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_isEmpty">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT"></field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_indexOf">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">text</field>
      </block>
    </value>
    <value name="FIND">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_charAt">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">text</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_getSubstring">
    <value name="STRING">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">text</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_changeCase">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_trim">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_count">
    <value name="SUB">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_replace">
    <value name="FROM">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="TO">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_reverse">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text"></shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <label text="Input/Output:" web-class="ioLabel"></label>
  <block type="text_print">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="text_prompt_ext">
    <value name="TEXT">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">abc</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
</category>
<category name="Lists" categorystyle="list_category">
  <block type="lists_create_with">
    <mutation items="0"></mutation>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_create_with"></block>
  <block type="lists_repeat">
    <value name="NUM">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">5</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_length"></block>
  <block type="lists_isEmpty"></block>
  <block type="lists_indexOf">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">list</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_getIndex">
    <value name="VALUE">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">list</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_setIndex">
    <value name="LIST">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">list</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_getSublist">
    <value name="LIST">
      <block type="variables_get">
        <field name="VAR">list</field>
      </block>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_split">
    <value name="DELIM">
      <shadow type="text">
        <field name="TEXT">,</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="lists_sort"></block>
  <block type="lists_reverse"></block>
</category>
<category name="Colour" categorystyle="colour_category">
  <block type="colour_picker"></block>
  <block type="colour_random"></block>
  <block type="colour_rgb">
    <value name="RED">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">100</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="GREEN">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">50</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="BLUE">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">0</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
  <block type="colour_blend">
    <value name="COLOUR1">
      <shadow type="colour_picker">
        <field name="COLOUR">#ff0000</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="COLOUR2">
      <shadow type="colour_picker">
        <field name="COLOUR">#3333ff</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
    <value name="RATIO">
      <shadow type="math_number">
        <field name="NUM">0.5</field>
      </shadow>
    </value>
  </block>
</category>
<sep></sep>
<category name="Variables" categorystyle="variable_category" custom="VARIABLE">
</category>
<category name="Functions" categorystyle="procedure_category"
custom="PROCEDURE"></category>
</xml>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check in following link hot exactly blocks look like

https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html